# Placing the last member of the list on the beginning of the list

Tags: c#

I am working on some exercises in C# and I had a task to input the list of any numbers in console and function should place the last member of the list to the first place, and shift all other members on the right.
For example, you can put "1234" in console, result should be "4123".
I tried different things and mostly to iterate through the list, but somehow I was always loosing one member of the list and i had duplicates in the new list.

After struggling for an hour or two, i decided to go easier way and I came up with the following code:

```
var list = new List<char>(); //this is list that is populated from console
var repositionedList = list; //this is list i am editing

char[] tempArray = new char[repositionedList.Count - 1];

for (var i = 0; i < repositionedList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    tempArray[i] = repositionedList[i];
}

repositionedList[0] = repositionedList[repositionedList.Count - 1];

for (var i = 1; i < repositionedList.Count; i++)
{
    repositionedList[i] = tempArray[i - 1];
}
```

Since I don't have any experience in coding, I am wondering if practice like this would not be acceptable. For example, I am creating new array, the most likely unnecessary and it may be costly, so there is much better way to accomplish the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) in C# has some helper methods that makes this much easier:

```
var list = new List<char>(); //this is list that is populated from console

var lastElement = list[list.Count - 1]; // Remember what the last element is
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1); // Remove the last element

list.Insert(0, lastElement); // Insert the element again, but at the first index
```

If you are allowed to use C# lists, this would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks for a replay! 
I thought the same at the beginning, but I thought that this will not shift the rest of a members. On the other words, I would loose the first member of a list. I have tried it and it works. 
Thank you once again!

Comment: @DavorN.Cacic Great to hear :) remember to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Uh, sorry, i have forgot to do so. 
This solution is totally accepted. 
Cheers!